# Can't upload large files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a problem uploading larger files then 2MB in CI. My website is running on the servers from one.com.
They have a max upload size from 96MB in there PHP.ini. So i guess that's ok. I have some lines in my .htaccess but still a white screen after uploading and no errors. Any suggestions how i can upload larger images then 2MB? Uploads under 2MB works perfectly.

.htaccess

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 96M
php_value post_max_size 96M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

controller

```
function voegfotostoe()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);    
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }   
    $datap = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    $gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '/../uploads');

    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    /* Size 200px x 200px */
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
    $config['new_image'] = $gallery_path . '/thumbs';
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 350;
    $config['height'] = 300;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();


    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['file_path'] . 'thumbs/' . $upload_data['orig_name'];
    $config['new_image'] = $gallery_path . '/vierkant';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = 200;
    $config['height'] = 200;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->crop();


    $thumb = $this->upload->data();
    $thumbname = $thumb['raw_name'] . $thumb['file_ext'];

    /* Size 600px X 600px */

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
    $config['new_image'] = $gallery_path . '/medium';
    $config['thumb_marker'] = '_medium';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 500;
    $config['height'] = 500;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $medium = $this->upload->data();
    $mediumname = $medium['raw_name'] . '_medium'. $medium['file_ext'];

$data = array(
    'fk_land' => $this->input->post('landid'),
    'titel' => $this->input->post('titel'),
    'period' => $this->input->post('period'),
    'size' => $this->input->post('size'),
    'info' => $this->input->post('info'),
    'region' => $this->input->post('region'),
    'cat_id' => $this->input->post('catsculp'),
    'color' => $this->input->post('color'),
    'order' => $this->input->post('landtoevoegen'),
    'gallery_name' => $this->input->post('painter'),
    'thumb_img' => $thumbname,
    'medium_img' => $mediumname

);

    if( $datap['upload_data']['orig_name'] != "" ) $data['gallery_img'] = $datap['upload_data']['orig_name'];
    $this->Cms_model->voegfototoe($data);
    redirect('home#toevoegen','refresh');   
}
```

Comment: i would run `phpinfo()` and make sure that `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are updated

Comment: what do you mean by no errors? what does $this->upload->display_errors(); shows?

Comment: My phpinfo() returns a max value of 32M. that should be enough. display_errors() returns nothing only a white screen when i upload an image over 2MB

Comment: Can you tell us what errors you are getting? As you could get into limit of size (you check that so its not this one), limit of execution time - max execution time of your script and your network speed can fail here. File permissions and so on. Try to get as much information as you can for us to help you more!.

Comment: Oh and there can be other error: what size if the image file - as GD shouldnt be used for BIG files (more than 2000x2000 pixels) and so on - as GD uses PHP Memory limits. If able change your code to using `imagick` library that does not consume php memory limit therefore can operate (AND VERY FAST) even on files 1gb in size (checked with memory limit for php at 32mb)... Took 8 seconds.

Comment: Thats exactly the problem. Uploading works perfectly but the gd2 library returns an error when converting the files greater then 2000x2000. Isn't there any standard lib from CI to handle this?

Comment: Ok i didn't know ImageMagick was a standard lib in CI. Thing is now, Uploading works but the image doesn't get resized/cropped anymore. Is there something else i need to change when changing the lib?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using post form, check in php.ini for the line where you have: "post_max_size" and change it to what you want example 8M or 0 for inlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Servers don't give access to change their default setting even if you place your own `php.ini` file and `.htaccess` in the root directory of the server. If you try `phpinfo()`, this will show you the local and server values. If your local values are not the same, then you don't have access to change. You should contact your server provider.